# How to query distinct records in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to query unique records using distinct in mysql but the problem is that it only returns a single column, how can I make it return all?

Here's my initial query:

```
SELECT  distinct(country_name)
FROM HST_LOCATION
WHERE person_id='1897'
ORDER BY date_updated DESC
group by country_name
```

Comment: Explain the original task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` clause makes that column distinct, there's no need to use the `DISTINCT` modifier. Just select all the columns and you should get what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM HST_LOCATION
WHERE person_id = '1897'
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY date_updated DESC
```